# Detail usage of `__disableTmpl`

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.3.3, there is a parameter added to some of the action items. For example, if we take the following from `module-cms/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/PageActions.php`

```
if (isset($item['page_id'])) {
                $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->editUrl, ['page_id' => $item['page_id']]),
                    'label' => __('Edit'),
                    '__disableTmpl' => true,
                ];
```

So, my question is that can anyone explain how is this `__disableTmpl` being implemented? I know there is a link regarding XSS mitigation in Magento at [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/xss-protection.html#ui-component-data-providers), however, it does not really explain what's going behind.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`__disableTmpl` used in JS.

Description of property:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7431f26b8c95398461457c019f5768d13842b44b/lib/web/mage/utils/template.js#L38-L40

`template` functionality usually used in Ui components. Allows to implement variables into string. E.g. `${$.name}.some_variable` where `name` is a variable of UI component.

`__disableTmpl` disable that functionality for specific object or property.